# how can I figure out the output of a c# project file (.csproj)

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I have a very large .NET solution with hundreds of projects (all c#) how can I figure out which of the projects is the application project to set as the start up project.

I was thinking of grepping the csproj files for some keyword that indicates it's an executable.

Thank you

Comment: there's no main? there's no default? then manually set each project as default using binary search in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Under Project -> Project Build Order, scroll to the bottom and start searching backwards.  The appropriate project is likely near the bottom if most of the other projects are dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately F5 yield the following message: "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly...."

Answer (score 0):

ok Found the answer

```
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

in the csproj file.